# When using table on a vector, the numbers in the names are out of order

Tags: r, variables

I have a data frame with a column `Session`. There are 215 unique values for `Session`, and I am trying to treat it as a categorical variable.

However, when I run `table(df$Session)`, the sessions are not appearing in order and some appear to be missing:

```r
table(df$Session)
  1  10 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109  11 110 111 113 114 115 116 117 118 
  6  11  20  14  17   8  14  11   8  14  15  17  12  16  15  17  19  26  24  31  28 
 12 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128  13 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 
 13  36  27  20  23  18  12  12  40  52  19  91  78  88  78   8   7  74   5   8   6 
 14 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149  15 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 
 14   7   6   7   5   3  75   3  70  75  68  16  68  67  67  68  58  69  70  68  26 
 159  16 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169  17 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 
 75  17  65  70  63  76  57  43  45  32  31  18  18  20  17  22  13  15  12   7   7 
178 179  18 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189  19 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 
  6   7  17   9   9  13  12  18  19  22  15   3  10   3  21  32  43  54  66  77  84 
197 198 199   2  20 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209  21 210 211 212 213 215 
 77  85  79   6  17  89  87  93  85  85  98  80  78  68  54  17  34  24  50  50  65 
 22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29   3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39   4  40 
 11  12  12  10  11   7   7  10   4   7   8   7   6   9  11  10  23  27  14   3  21 
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49   5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59   6 
 27  16  16  18  10  12  19   7   6   4   5  13  21  17  25  31  32  30  15  10   3 
 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69   7  70  71  73  74  75  76  77  78  79   8 
 18  17  11  14  14  15  18  11  13   9   7  13  12   7   8   8   9  12   8   9   6 
 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89   9  90  91  92  93  94  95  97  98  99 
  1  11   8  17  20  13  14  18  19  19   9  14  16  12  15  17  19  13   7  16
```

If we only look at a couple of columns:

```r
table(df$Session)
# 1  10 100 101  ... 197 198 199   2  20 200 201 202  ...
# 6  11  20  14  ...  77  85  79   6  17  89  87  93  ...
```

Why are they not ordered by number (1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 10, 100)? And how can I correct this?

Comment: please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or the output of `dput(df)`. You can convert the `Session` var to `factor` with `as.factor`. If you want to order your `Session` you can use `table(sort(df$Session))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

The variable will be sorted correctly if you make it `numeric` first:

```r
table(as.numeric(df$Session))
table(as.factor(as.numeric(df$Session)))
```

**Explanation**

Your variable is or was of the class `character`. The order of your variable is alphabetically, i.e. what would happen if you sort a `character` vector. Try: `sort(c("1", "11", "2"))`. When you apply `factor` or `as.factor` to a `character` vector, the levels will be ordered as such (see `?factor`):

> levels: an optional vector of the unique values (as character strings) that x might have taken. The default is the unique set of values taken by as.character(x), sorted into increasing order of x. Note that this set can be specified as smaller than sort(unique(x)).

Keep in mind that R reads in numbers as `numeric` by default. If you expected the column to be `numeric` from the start but R made it `character`, then you likely have values in there that are not strictly numbers. It is important to find out *why* the vector was `character`.

**Reproducible example**

```r
vec <- c(22, 11, 3, 2, 1)

table(vec) # correct: numeric
# 1  2  3 11 22 
# 1  1  1  1  1 

table(as.character(vec)) # incorrect: character
# 1 11  2 22  3 
# 1  1  1  1  1 

table(as.factor(as.character(vec))) # incorrect: character -> factor
# 1 11  2 22  3 
# 1  1  1  1  1 

table(as.factor(vec)) # correct: numeric -> factor
# 1  2  3 11 22 
# 1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Elia and slamballais :D Both ways worked, thank you so much :D Best wishes :3